# Sidebar dropdown to the side Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found a sidebar through a tutorials site which I really like! I also adjusted it a little so it is like how I want it. I'll add my code:

### Style:

```
body {
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #4b2177;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
padding: 4px 4px 4px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
color: #FFFFFF;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
transition: margin-left .5s;
padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
.sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
.sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

### Navigator:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <hr>
    <a href="{{ url('/documentation') }}">Documentation</a>
    <a href="{{ url('/userguide') }}">User Guide</a>
    <hr>
</div>
```

### And JS:

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "150px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    }
</script>
```

### Other HTML:

```
<span style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;color:#4b2177" onClick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

I would like to use some sort of drop down menu which in the sidenav. So i looked and I found this sidebar with dropdown to the side (see image). I tried to use the code from the website: http://bootstrap-layout.themekit.io/sidebar-menu/dropdown.html

```
<li class="sidebar-menu-item">
    <a href="#" class="sidebar-menu-button" data-toggle="sidebar-dropdown">Reports</a>

    <!-- Submenu -->
    <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
      <li class="sidebar-menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-menu-button">Another menu item</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-menu-button">Regular menu item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work like a dropdown. It just shows all the elements in a `<li>`.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle of your code?

Comment: Do you want drop-down(submenu) of outside of the sidebar menu..As you shown in the screenshot ?

Comment: Rollback your "improvements" till it becomes to behave as it should do.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq Like in the image!

Comment: This is an example! http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push @AbhishekPandey

Comment: @Anna Jeanine:: Do you want the feature like: push sidebar menu? which you have shown in W3Schools website ?

Comment: @SayedRafeeq I'm not totally understading you.. I want to have the sidenav from the example which I shared, but the optional dropdown to the side.

Comment: @Anna Jeanine:: As per your given example that dropdown will not work in responsive mode. That's why I'm trying to ask you whether you want this dropdown menu in responsive mode aslo with push sidenav feature. :)